# Is it possible/sensible to use the gradle war and ear plugin in the same project?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, war, ear

I found that the ear plugin overrides the war plugin and prevents the war task being called.  I got around it by calling it directly.

Is this remotely sensible or should I give up and move to a multi-project setup in eclipse and gradle?

```
ear {
    doFirst {
        println " - force build war..."
        tasks.war.execute()
    }

    from("$destinationDir") {
        exclude('nz')
        rename ('TrialApp(.*)(.war)', 'TrialApp.war')
        include 'TrialApp*.war'
        into('')
    }
    deploymentDescriptor {  
                applicationName = "trialapp"
                initializeInOrder = true
                displayName = "Trial App"  
                description = "Trial App EAR for Gradle documentation"
                libraryDirectory = "WEB-INF/lib"  
                webModule("TrialApp.war", "TrialApp")  
    }
}
```

Comment: this question is, for me, far more useful than any gradle documention I've yet come across.  My two cents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Ear plugin doesn't *override* the War plugin, it simply doesn't execute the `war` task by default. Anyway, what you are trying to do is certainly possible. Instead of adding a dependency to a separate war project (as is described in the [documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/ear_plugin.html) you can simply depend on the `war` task itself.

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'ear'

dependencies {
    deploy files(war)
}
```